# "Windows Stopped Working" Issue when running big .txt files

Tags: c, memory, codeblocks, allocation, maze

i was working with Code::Blocks and implementing a maze algorithm in C language. I have a working code with relatively small input files (Input files are .txt files and they are mazes). But when i try to run my code with the bigger input files, the compiler stops working. There is no error message in the log panel, it just stops at runtime.

I can not find the problem and dont know where the problem is coming from as well.I suspect that some memory allocation issue causing this.

Here is my code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "QueueImplementation.h"

int numberOfLines;
int Coord_To_Node_Number(int x, int y, int n);
int * Node_Number_To_Coord(int node_num, int n);
void BFS(char maze[][numberOfLines+1], int coord_S_x, int coord_S_y, int coord_G_x, int coord_G_y, int n);
void RecursiveSearchAndPrintMaze(int parent[], struct Queue* shortestPathQueue, int popped_node, int starting_node, char maze[][numberOfLines+1], int n);


int Coord_To_Node_Number(int x, int y, int n)
{
    return (y * n) + x + 1;
}


int * Node_Number_To_Coord(int node_num, int n)
{
    static int coordinates[2];
    coordinates[0] = 0;
    coordinates[1] = 0;

    //int bölüm = node_num / n;
    coordinates[0] = (node_num - 1) % n;
    coordinates[1] = (node_num - 1) / n;
    return coordinates;
}


void RecursiveSearchAndPrintMaze(int parent[], struct Queue* shortestPathQueue, int popped_node, int starting_node, char maze[][numberOfLines+1], int n)
        {
            if (parent[popped_node] == starting_node)
            {
                int number_of_steps = shortestPathQueue->size + 2;
                int * coordinatesss;
                while (isEmpty(shortestPathQueue) == 0)
                {
                    coordinatesss = Node_Number_To_Coord(dequeue(shortestPathQueue), n);
                    maze[coordinatesss[1]][coordinatesss[0]] = '*';
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                    {
                        printf("%c", maze[i][k]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                printf("Number of steps= %d\n\n", number_of_steps);
                return;
            }
            enqueue(shortestPathQueue, parent[popped_node]);
            popped_node = parent[popped_node];
            RecursiveSearchAndPrintMaze(parent, shortestPathQueue, popped_node, starting_node, maze, n);

            return;
        }




void BFS(char maze[][numberOfLines+1], int coord_S_x, int coord_S_y, int coord_G_x, int coord_G_y, int n){
    printf("\nBFS Maze\n");
    int parent[250001];
    int discovered[250001];
    int popped_node;
    int *coords_int_arr;


    int starting_node = Coord_To_Node_Number(coord_S_x, coord_S_y, n); // returns 41
    int end_node = Coord_To_Node_Number(coord_G_x, coord_G_y, n); // returns 80

    int disc_counter = 0;
    discovered[starting_node] = 1; disc_counter++;
    struct Queue* queue = createQueue(300000);
    enqueue(queue, starting_node);

    int east_node, south_node, north_node, west_node;
    int x_new;
    int y_new;

    printf("In while...");
    while (isFull(queue) == 0)
            {
                popped_node = dequeue(queue); // 41

                if (popped_node == end_node)
                {
                    struct Queue* shortestPathQueue = createQueue(5000);

                    printf("End node reached");
                    RecursiveSearchAndPrintMaze(parent, shortestPathQueue, popped_node, starting_node, maze, numberOfLines);
                    break;
                }

                // Go east
                coords_int_arr = Node_Number_To_Coord(popped_node, n);

                if (coords_int_arr[0] + 1 >= 0 && coords_int_arr[0] + 1 < n && coords_int_arr[1] >= 0 && coords_int_arr[1] < n)
                {
                    east_node = popped_node + 1; // 42
                    x_new = coords_int_arr[0] + 1;  // 1
                    y_new = coords_int_arr[1];  // 4

                    if (*(*(maze + y_new)+x_new) == '#') { }
                    else if (*(*(maze + y_new)+x_new) == '.' || *(*(maze + y_new)+x_new) == 'G')
                    {
                        if (discovered[east_node] == 0)   // east_coord eger discovered listesinde yoksa listeye ekle ve sonra queue'ya ekle
                        {
                            enqueue(queue, east_node);
                            parent[east_node] = popped_node;
                            discovered[east_node] = 1;
                            disc_counter++;
                        }
                    }

                }
                // Go South
                coords_int_arr = Node_Number_To_Coord(popped_node, n);

                if (coords_int_arr[0] >= 0 && coords_int_arr[0] < n && coords_int_arr[1] + 1 >= 0 && coords_int_arr[1] + 1 < n)
                {
                    south_node = popped_node + n; // 51
                    x_new = coords_int_arr[0];  // 0
                    y_new = coords_int_arr[1] + 1;  // 5

                    if (*(*(maze + y_new)+x_new) == '#') { }
                    else if (*(*(maze + y_new)+x_new) == '.' || *(*(maze + y_new)+x_new) == 'G')
                    {
                        if (discovered[south_node] == 0)   // east_coord eger discovered listesinde yoksa listeye ekle ve sonra queue'ya ekle
                        {
                            enqueue(queue, south_node);
                            parent[south_node] = popped_node;
                            discovered[south_node] = 1;
                            disc_counter++;
                        }
                    }

                }
                // Go North
                coords_int_arr = Node_Number_To_Coord(popped_node, n);

                if (coords_int_arr[0] >= 0 && coords_int_arr[0] < n && coords_int_arr[1] - 1 >= 0 && coords_int_arr[1] - 1 < n)
                {
                    north_node = popped_node - n; // 31
                    x_new = coords_int_arr[0];  // 0
                    y_new = coords_int_arr[1] - 1;  // 3

                    if (*(*(maze + y_new)+x_new) == '#') { }
                    else if (*(*(maze + y_new)+x_new) == '.' || *(*(maze + y_new)+x_new) == 'G')
                    {
                        if (discovered[north_node] == 0)   // east_coord eger discovered listesinde yoksa listeye ekle ve sonra queue'ya ekle
                        {
                            enqueue(queue, north_node);
                            parent[north_node] = popped_node;
                            discovered[north_node] = 1;
                            disc_counter++;
                        }
                    }

                }
                // Go West
                coords_int_arr = Node_Number_To_Coord(popped_node, n);

                if (coords_int_arr[0] - 1 >= 0 && coords_int_arr[0] - 1 < n && coords_int_arr[1] >= 0 && coords_int_arr[1] < n)
                {
                    west_node = popped_node - 1; // 42
                    x_new = coords_int_arr[0] - 1;  // -1
                    y_new = coords_int_arr[1];  // 4

                    if (*(*(maze + y_new)+x_new) == '#') { }
                    else if (*(*(maze + y_new)+x_new) == '.' || *(*(maze + y_new)+x_new) == 'G')
                    {
                        if (discovered[west_node] == 0)   // east_coord eger discovered listesinde yoksa listeye ekle ve sonra queue'ya ekle
                        {
                            enqueue(queue, west_node);
                            parent[west_node] = popped_node;
                            discovered[west_node] = 1;
                            disc_counter++;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
return;
}




int main()
{
    printf("******************************\n");
    printf("      MAZE\n");
    printf("******************************\n\n");
    int coord_S_x = 0;
    int coord_S_y = 0;
    int coord_G_x = 0;
    int coord_G_y = 0;

    // First we will read the text file and attain the necessary variables
    FILE *fPointer;
    fPointer = fopen("C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\AdvProgTec1\\ws19\\uebung_6\\c_part\\deneme_1\\t500.maz", "r");

    fscanf(fPointer, "%d", &numberOfLines); // Reads the first line
    printf("numberOfLines: %d\n", numberOfLines);

    char singleLine[numberOfLines];
    char maze[numberOfLines][numberOfLines+1];

    for (int i=0; i<numberOfLines; i++){
        fscanf(fPointer, " %s", singleLine);
        strcpy(maze[i], singleLine);
        char findS = 'S';
        char findG = 'G';

        const char *ptrS = strchr(singleLine, findS);
        const char *ptrG = strchr(singleLine, findG);
        if(ptrS)
        {
            int indexS = ptrS - singleLine;
            coord_S_x = indexS;
            coord_S_y = i;
        }
        if(ptrG)
        {
            int indexG = ptrG - singleLine;
            coord_G_x = indexG;
            coord_G_y = i;
        }

    }
    fclose(fPointer);

    printf("int coord_S_x = %d \n", coord_S_x);
    printf("int coord_S_y = %d \n", coord_S_y);
    printf("int coord_G_x = %d \n", coord_G_x);
    printf("int coord_G_y = %d \n", coord_G_y);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Checkpoint");

    BFS(maze, coord_S_x, coord_S_y, coord_G_x, coord_G_y, numberOfLines);











    return 0;
}
```

and there is a header file as well;

```
// C program for array implementation of queue
#include <limits.h>

// A structure to represent a queue
struct Queue
{
    int front, rear, size;
    int capacity;
    int* array;
};

// function to create a queue of given capacity.
// It initializes size of queue as 0
struct Queue* createQueue(int capacity)
{
    struct Queue* queue = (struct Queue*) malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    queue->capacity = capacity;
    queue->front = queue->size = 0;
    queue->rear = capacity - 1;  // This is important, see the enqueue
    queue->array = (int*) malloc(queue->capacity * sizeof(int));
    return queue;
}

// Queue is full when size becomes equal to the capacity
int isFull(struct Queue* queue)
{  return (queue->size == queue->capacity);  }

// Queue is empty when size is 0
int isEmpty(struct Queue* queue)
{  return (queue->size == 0); }

// Function to add an item to the queue.
// It changes rear and size
void enqueue(struct Queue* queue, int item)
{
    if (isFull(queue))
        return;
    queue->rear = (queue->rear + 1)%queue->capacity;
    queue->array[queue->rear] = item;
    queue->size = queue->size + 1;
//    printf("%d enqueued to queue\n", item);
}

// Function to remove an item from queue.
// It changes front and size
int dequeue(struct Queue* queue)
{
    if (isEmpty(queue))
        return INT_MIN;
    int item = queue->array[queue->front];
    queue->front = (queue->front + 1)%queue->capacity;
    queue->size = queue->size - 1;
    return item;
}

// Function to get front of queue
int front(struct Queue* queue)
{
    if (isEmpty(queue))
        return INT_MIN;
    return queue->array[queue->front];
}

// Function to get rear of queue
int rear(struct Queue* queue)
{
    if (isEmpty(queue))
        return INT_MIN;
    return queue->array[queue->rear];
}
```

Can anyone suggest anything??
Thanks

Comment: The best suggestion is to debug the code. How to do that? Run it in a debugger and/or add more debug print statements to trace the code execution. This may also be helpful: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: maybe this allocation `char maze[numberOfLines][numberOfLines+1];` will be too expensive and you will exhaust the stack?